# PHP Api call is not working in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

**this is my code not getting debugger not and getting any response
 please help me**

```
return $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: mysite.com/index.php/mobileapi/index/gettoken',

        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        transformRequest: function (obj) {
            var str = [];
            for (var p in obj)
                str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
            return str.join("&");
        },
        data: { 'username': "email", 'password': "password", 'type': "buyer" }
    }).then(function (result) {
debugger;

        return result.data;
    });
```

Comment: Add a second callback the then(), that will be called in ase of an error. Open your dev tools and look what happens in the network panel. But hey, `url: mysite.com/index.php/mobileapi/index/gettoken'` is not valid JavaScript, and even if it was, it wouldn't be a valid URL. So you should also open your console and fix all the syntax errors.

Comment: showing success call in network with proper response

Comment: then it's working. Congratulations.

Comment: now its working because of cors origin error it not waiting for response